# How to create a proxy object in R

Tags: r, proxy

I'd like to create a generic proxy mechanism which could intercept any access to the object. Basically for a function it would look like this:

```
proxy <- function (fn) function (...) {
  do.call (fn, list (...));
}
```

This way I could for example easily add logging. Playing around with assigning formals I can even get it to look like the passed in original function, however this doesn't work for anything that's not a function, is it possible to extend this concept for other types? Some way I could wrap a number and receive a callback anytime it's accessed

Comment: Actually you're right, I'll edit the question, the problem is not with the operators, but the operands

Comment: Can you give an example of something that's not working for you? I'm guessing the problem is you're forcing evaluation of the parameters with `list()`. Maybe you want `proxy <- function (fn) function (...) {do.call (fn, as.list(substitute(...())));}`

Comment: Maybe you want `makeActiveBinding`?

Comment: `makeActiveBinding` is kind of what I want, I'll accept it as answer if you want to write it up